# Check if an inline SVG image is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, svg, inline-svg

Is there a way to check if an `<image>` in an inline svg has been loaded? Regular imgs have a complete property to check if the `<img>` has been loaded, but not `<image>`. I want to add a load event listener only if the image hasn't already been loaded.

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/danohlsen/pen/VMgzzV) of the following:

```
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <image xlink:href="http://placebeard.it/300/300" width="300" height="300"></image>
</svg>


<script>
  var image = document.querySelector('image');
  console.log(image.complete) // undefined
  if (!image.complete && image.complete != null){ // does not work because there is no complete property of svg image, unlike a regular img
    image.addEventListener('load', function(){
      alert('image loaded');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That should be "if (!image.complete)" shouldn't it?

Comment: I have reverted your code sample back to its broken state to avoid confusing future readers of this question.

Comment: The question is the same regardless of an error in the code: How to check if an SVG image has been loaded. To avoid confusion, you could just delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can still add a load event.  There is just no property to tell if it has already been loaded or not.

```js
var image = document.querySelector('image');
image.addEventListener('load', function(){
  alert('image loaded');
});
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <image xlink:href="http://placebeard.it/300/300" width="300" height="300"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sure, but if the image has loaded before the load event listener is added, it will never fire.

Comment: Yeah, Dan0 is right, if image is loaded the event wont fire. Did you find the solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to put the image source in a data attribute, add a load event listener then swap in the xlink:href. Works in Chrome and Firefox.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/danohlsen/pen/wrOwLP)

```
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <image xlink:href="http://placebeard.it/300/300" width="300" height="300"></image>
</svg>

<script>
  var image = document.querySelector('image');
  image.addEventListener('load', function(){
    alert('image loaded');
  });

  image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 
  image.dataset.src);
</script>
```